# Html Agility Pack messing with my javascript

Tags: javascript, html-agility-pack

I'm using the Html Agility Pack to output some javascript in the head of my document. But after saving the document to the file system I recognized that the javascript source has been modified. I guess this happens because HAP is trying to validate my script. Is it possible to prevent this? As you can see below I already tried setting different options.

My code using HAP:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionCheckSyntax = false;
htmlDoc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false;
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = false;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

HtmlNode headNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
headNode.AddScriptNode(htmlDoc, "../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js");
```

Extension Method for adding the script tag

```
public static void AddScriptNode(this HtmlNode headNode, HtmlDocument htmlDoc, string filePath)
{
    string content = "";

    using (StreamReader rdr = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        content = rdr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    if(headNode != null)
    {
        HtmlNode scripts = htmlDoc.CreateElement("script");
        scripts.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
        scripts.InnerHtml = "\n" + content + "\n";
        headNode.AppendChild(scripts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My assumption: when using `scripts.InnerHtml` AgilityPack tries to parse the content as HTML. So if there are tags there they will be converted to HTML nodes.

To avoid this you should set the content of the `<script>` as text. Unfortunately, `HtmlNode.InnerText` property is a read-only but there is a workaround for this. You could just add a text(a comment node will be preferrable) node to your `<script>` node:

```
if(headNode != null)
{
    HtmlNode scripts = htmlDoc.CreateElement("script");
    scripts.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
    scripts.AppendChild(htmlDoc.CreateComment("\n" + content + "\n"));
    headNode.AppendChild(scripts);
}
```

Here the body of your script will be added as a comment node (`<!--` and `-->` will be added).

Comment: A note to others: if you want to add the script tag without having the html comments you can do the following `scripts.AppendChild(htmlDoc.CreateTextNode(content));`